# How to discard change to git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I changed the commit pointer of a git submodule:

```
% git status
# On branch fix
# Your branch is behind 'origin/fix' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   app/lib (new commits)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Yet when I do `git checkout`, nothing changes:

```
% git checkout -- app/lib && git status
# On branch fix
# Your branch is behind 'origin/fix' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   app/lib (new commits)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Here's the diff:

```
% git diff
diff --git a/app/lib b/app/lib
index d670460..83baae6 160000
--- a/app/web-lib
+++ b/app/web-lib
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit d670460b4b4aece5915caf5c68d12f560a9fe3e4
+Subproject commit 83baae61804e65cc73a7201a7252750c76066a30
```

Any idea why this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Git doesn't update submodules automatically when the SHA in them has changed.

You either need to `git submodule update` which will put the submodule back to the expected SHA,
or `git add app/lib` which will change the expected SHA to the current value in the submodule.